# How to Make Sense of Fourier Transform Results in Audio Frequency Analysis

Tags: python, numpy, fft, frequency-analysis, audio-analysis

I am doing audio analysis in Python. My end goal is to get a list of frequencies and their respective volumes, like `{ frequency : volume (0.0 - 1.0) }`.

I have my audio data as a list of frames with values between `-1.0` and `+1.0`. I used numpy's fourier transform on this list — `numpy.fftpack.fft()`. But the resulting data makes no sense to me.

I do understand that the fourier transform transforms from the time to the frequency domain, but not quite how it mathematically works. That's why I don't quite understand the results.

- What do the values in the list that `numpy.fftpack.fft()` returns mean? How do I work with it/interpret it?
- What would be the max/min values of the fourier transform performed on a list as described above be?
- How can I get to my end goal of a dictionary in the form `{ frequency : volume (0.0 - 1.0) }`?

Thank you. Sorry if my lack of understanding of the fourier transform made you facepalm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the FFT of a single period of a sine wave:

```
>>> t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
>>> x = np.sin(t)
>>> f = np.fft.rfft(x)
>>> np.round(np.abs(f), 0)
array([  0.,  50.,   1.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.])
```

The FFT returns an array of complex numbers which give the amplitude and phase of the frequencies. Assuming you're only interested in the amplitude, I've used `np.abs` to get the magnitude for each frequency and rounded it to the nearest integer using `np.round(__, 0)`. You can see the spike at index `1` indicating a sin wave with period equal to the number of samples was found.

Now make the wave a bit more complex

```
>>> x = np.sin(t) + np.sin(3*t) + np.sin(5*t)
>>> f = np.fft.rfft(x)
>>> np.round(np.abs(f), 0)
array([  0.,  50.,   1.,  50.,   0.,  48.,   4.,   2.,   2.,   1.,   1.,
         1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   1.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,
         0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.])
```

We now see spikes at indicies 1, 3 & 5 corresponding to our input. Sine waves with periods of `n`, `n/3` and `n/5` (where n in the number of input samples).

**EDIT**

Here's a good conceptual explanation of the Fourier transform: http://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/

Comment: The phase part of the result is what confused me. Thanks for the explanation and link.

Comment: One more question, is the maximum value after the transform always half the magnitude of the input?